# How to add path to gcc's search dirs?

Tags: gcc

command

```
gcc -print-search-dirs
```

returns:

```
install: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/
programs: =/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/bin/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/bin/i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/bin/
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/lib/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/:/lib/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

How to add some other path to libraries section? I want to make my custom library available via flag -lmylib instead specific path.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to install th library to `/usr/lib` on a user's system. The only way to change the built-in specs is by using a custom specs file (not recommended!) and this also requires an additional argument.

Either install it to `/usr/lib` or pass the location as an argument when linking.

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy the path printed as you showed, and prepend your desired path element and pass it to the `-B` option.