# How to add source code directory to gcc's search path?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I searched here and found this : [How to add path to gcc's search dirs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949292/how-to-add-path-to-gccs-search-dirs)

But it doesn't answer my question. I want to add a path to the programs section.

I have stored the source code at `C:\C\` but everytime I try to compile these programs by    `gcc prog.c -o ha`, it says "No such file or directory". I have to type the entire path everytime. Also tell me how to remove a directory from gcc's programs path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no option in GCC that does what you want. If you don't want to type out the entire name, simply `cd C:\C` and then run `gcc prog.c -o ha`. GCC's translation unit parameters are always either absolute or relative to the current working directory.

Comment: I changed the directory and then typed `gcc prog.c` and it worked. After this, ho do I run the program? I tried typing `prog` and `./prog` but none of them worked.

Comment: If I don't specify the name of output file myself, it automtically names it as "a.exe" and hence typing `prog` does not work. But why does this happen? Why is the output file not named as "prog.exe"?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But the answer is that gcc, by default, outputs the file "a.exe" or "a.out" (on UNIX). You need to tell it the name of the output file you want, if you want something different, e.h. "gcc -o prog.exe prog.c". The reason is that in real projects, you mostly specify more than one input file, for later linkage, and hence there's no point in trying to infer the name you want in those cases... So to keep it simple, it's that way for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

in your Makefile or in the shell add [-I option](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.htm):

```
gcc -I/path/to/include prog.c
```

**EDIT:**
I DIDN'T UNDERSTAND YOUR QUESTION.

If you want to compile `prog.c` from every directory add C:\c\ to your path environment variable.

or do this:

```
pushd && cd C:\C\ && gcc prog.c -o ha && popd
```

Comment: I use Windows. I tried this command but it doesn't work. I got the same error again. `gcc -I/C:/C/ prog.c`

Comment: Here's what I did. I added `C:\C\`to the path environment variables. I opened cmd and typed `gcc prog.c`but it still shows the same error. Do I still have to type `gcc C:\C\prog.c`?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=NEWPATH 
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```